# How to add ArrayList of a super class into another class

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism, abstract

For my assignment I have to create three classes, one superclass called Publication, a subclass of that called Book, and another class called Publisher. The publisher is not stated to be inherited from publication in my assignment but needs to make a arraylist and a addPublication() method that should accept a Publication and adds it to the publication ArrayList inside Publisher. I'm not sure how to do this part.

Comment: TL;DR Please shorten your code and provide a short, but complete example.

Comment: Frontrunner for hw dump of the day!

Comment: Take a few moments and format your code in the question.

Comment: What is your question, _specifically_? It currently looks like you want us to do your work for you. Please clarify.

Comment: _I'm not sure how to do this part_ is not a problem statement, nor a question. Please take the tour and read the help center to understand what is expected of you on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare a list attribute in Publisher class: `private List<Publication> publications = new ArrayList<Publication>();`

Then you can add a `addPublication` method:

```
public void addPublication(Publication publication) {
  this.publications.add(publication);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your publisher class put:

```
private List<Publication> publications = new ArrayList<Publication>();

public void addPublication(Publication p) {
     publications.add(p);
}
```

Then your main can look like this:

```
public class Helper {
     public static void main (String[] args) {
            Publisher publisher1 = new Publisher("name", "adress", "contactname");
            Book b = new Book("put the whole bunch of correct parameters here");
            publisher1.addPublication(b);
     }
}
```

Now your publisher1 has an arraylist with Book b in it. Hope this helps.